# Word like 'sailor', without the connotation of sailing

Tags: single-word-requests

I have several qualifications in what the RYA (UK authority for such qualifications) calls powerboating or motor cruising. These are small-to-medium sized boats with engines, and no sails. I would like to be able to say sentences of the form "I am a keen *x*" but using the word *sailor* suggests that I know about sailing (which I don't).

I realise that in other contexts (for example, sailors in the Navy) the word doesn't have those connotations, but I believe it would in the contexts I want to use it. What alternatives could I use?

Comment: Is there a question here? If you're looking for alternatives, what about boater? Mariner? Motorboater? Powerboater?

Comment: "Boater" is the term used around here.

Comment: 'Boatsman' is probably unusual enough to make people at least examine likelihoods. Especially if you're a lady.

Comment: @HotLicks 'Boater' first brings to mind the hat, at least in the UK.

Comment: What did your dictionary of choice, or the RYA rules, leave unclear?

Answer (score 2):

The word you're looking for is ***boater*** ... this is what [the RYA would call you](http://www.rya.org.uk/knowledge-advice/planning-environment/Pages/economic-contribution-of-the-recreational-boater.aspx). It's the best generic word for a boat user. The only caveat is that it includes all vessels, including rowing boats, kayaks, canal barges, pedalos, etc. If you cross oceans in a superyacht, you might find *boater* slightly beneath your dignity!

It's also fine to describe a motorboat user as a ***sailor*** (yes, I disagree with the premise of your question). Certainly so if you go on lengthy voyages.

> sailor: 2) a traveller by water https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sailor

... most people understand that wind power does not a sailor make, in my experience. (I do sailboats. My motor-cruising friends all describe themselves as sailors without fear of reproach or confusion.)

Similarly, anybody who uses a boat for pleasure, rather than commerce or transport is a ***yachtsman*** (although that word is also slightly more associated with puff power)

I'd suggest that you can safely describe yourself as a yachtsman or sailor around anyone who knows boats, but keep *"I sail a powerboat"* in reserve for lubbers.

Answer (score 0):

You're a **mariner**.

> 1. a person who directs or assists in the navigation of a ship; sailor.

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mariner)

"I am a keen mariner."

And since you're in the UK, you probably won't be confused with [those other guys](https://www.mlb.com/mariners).

Comment: I'm not sure how it's used elsewhere, but in the UK 'mariner' is normally reserved for those who go to sea as a career: either on a commercial freight  vessel, or the navy. You wouldn't call someone who works on a fishing trawler a mariner, even.

Comment: @ArchContrarian sure. I agree. Even further, in my experience (U.S. Pacific Northwest, if it makes a difference) your examples would hold up for "sailor" just as much as "mariner". You'd call the guy a "fisherman" or "crabber" or "dude in a boat". OP mentioned qualifications of some flavor, which sounds formal enough to me that he'd be looking for a formal enough word. Mariner, to me, is basically "sailor" without the explicit "sail" part, which is what I think we're looking for.